# How can I fix the ValueError when building the model in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run the code written on https://github.com/MG2033/ShuffleNet, just by running `python main.py --config config/test.json` , I get the following error when ‌buling the model:

```
Building the model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 69, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 35, in main
model = ShuffleNet(config_args)
File "/home/farzaneh/PycharmProjects/shufflenet code/ShuffleNet-master/model.py", line 29, in __init__ 
self.__build()
File "/home/farzaneh/PycharmProjects/shufflenet code/ShuffleNet-master/  
model.py", line 134, in __build
self.__init_output()
File "/home/farzaneh/PycharmProjects/shufflenet code/ShuffleNet-master  /model.py", line 91, in __init_output
self.check_op = tf.add_check_numerics_ops()
File "/home/farzaneh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow /python/ops/numerics.py", line 75, in add_check_numerics_ops
raise ValueError("`tf.add_check_numerics_ops() is not compatible "
ValueError: `tf.add_check_numerics_ops() is not compatible with TensorFlow    control flow operations such as `tf.cond()` or `tf.while_loop()`.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: which version of tensorflow do you have?

Comment: version of tensorflow is :1.3.0

Comment: I upgraded Tensorflow to Verizon 1.8.0.But it still has the same error.What should I do, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/MG2033/ShuffleNet/blob/master/README.md) of shuffle.NET, you need to provide a path to the config file as argument, as following: `python main.py --config config/test.json`. And there should be a config.

**EDIT: After I looked into it:**
Apparently, the error is right and add_check_numerics_ops is incompatible with while_loops and stuff. In the code you can also see that this line was just added for debugging to handle nans, which normally should not occur. Therefore I guess you can just comment out this part. Finally I found that there is this [issue](https://github.com/MG2033/ShuffleNet/issues/11) on the project too, which gives me the feeling that there is really an issue with the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not professional in coding. what do you mean about " you need to provide a config file as argument."? First downloaded the files from the site and then opened the terminal in their storage location. after that I run the following command:python main.py --config config/test.json.      The output was

Comment: Thanks for your help. I comment out that part and  that error was fixed.But unfortunately I face a new error in initializing weights. What should I do?
  

  File "/home/farzaneh/PycharmProjects/shufflenet code/ShuffleNet-master/utils.py", line 89, in load_obj
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'weights.pkl'

Comment: https://github.com/MG2033/ShuffleNet/blob/master/config/README_FOR_COMMON_ISSUE you should look at this link then. There it is explained why it does not work